# How to run readline function in R?

Tags: r, input, readline

I have written an R code in R with an input statement. If I select the whole code and run it, it does not ask for the input and then shows error as the

```
m <- as.numeric(readline(print("Enter number of variables: ")))   #Asking for number of rows

n <- as.numeric(readline(print("Enter number of equations: ")))   #Asking for number of columns
   
A <- rep(0,m*n)
```

the error shown is

```
Error in rep(0, m * n) : invalid 'times' argument
```

However, if I select one command at a time and execute the code it runs smoothly.
It is tedious to shuffle between the script and console, is there an easier way to do this?

UPDATE: The easiest way that I figured out is to use the 'SOURCE' option to run the code instead to 'RUN' option
Thank you for your help

Comment: The error is produced because for each reading command the next is run before entering any number, so `m` and `n` are `NA`. I believe your issue is related to what is explained in `?readline` about `interactive sessions`.

Comment: @iago yes the code works fine if I execute each command separately. However is there any easier way in which I can run the whole script together?

Comment: I do not know, but I understand that if it is possible, it cannot be with the `readline` function

Comment: @iago yes it is similar to the interactive sessions. I don't know how to incorporate that in my code but I'll try. Thank you for your help